# Making equal size lists in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have 3 different lists of unequal length.

I want to append the shorter lists with "X" and make sizes equal to the length of the longest list.

```
A = [10,20,30,40,50]
B = ["A", "B", "C"]
C = ["X1", "X2"]
```

After appending "X" , it should be like the following:

```
A = [10,20,30,40,50]
B = ["A", "B", "C", "X","X"]
C = ["P1", "P2", "X", "X", "X"]
```

I have used the below code for achieving it,

```
for i, a in enumerate(A):
    if i < len(B):
        pass
    else:
        B.append('X')
```

How can i do it efficiently in python ?

Comment: you should not use semicolon, if you don't need to do anything – use `pass` or just don't write this block

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calculate the max length and for each list, append the delta.

In Python, `List` has a binary operator `+` to concat multiple lists together, as well as `*` to tile itself.

```
A = [10,20,30,40,50]
B = ["A", "B", "C"]
C = ["X1", "X2"]
max_length = max(max(len(A), len(B)), len(C))
A += ['X'] * (max_length - len(A))
B += ['X'] * (max_length - len(B))
C += ['X'] * (max_length - len(C))
```

Then organize them using a container list, for less repeated codes and better extensibility.

```
A = [10,20,30,40,50]
B = ["A", "B", "C"]
C = ["X1", "X2"]

arrays = [A, B, C]
max_length = 0
for array in arrays:
    max_length = max(max_length, len(array))

for array in arrays:
    array += ['X'] * (max_length - len(array))
```

Result:

```
print(A) # [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
print(B) # ['A', 'B', 'C', 'X', 'X']
print(C) # ['X1', 'X2', 'X', 'X', 'X']
```

Comment: `max` can work with any non-empty sequence of containers

Answer (score 10):

Use the `extend` method

```
B.extend(['X'] * (len(A)-len(B)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Write function that makes this for you

```
A = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
B = ["A", "B", "C"]
C = ["X1", "X2"]


def extend_with_extra_elements(*some_lists):
    max_some_lists_length = max(map(len, some_lists))
    for some_list in some_lists:
        extra_elements_count = max_some_lists_length - len(some_list)
        extra_elements = ['X'] * extra_elements_count
        yield some_list + extra_elements


A, B, C = extend_with_extra_elements(A, B, C)
```

efficient enough

Answer (score 2):

The python `itertools` module has a lot of nifty functions that are good for cases like this.  For example:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest, izip
>>> A = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
>>> B = ["A", "B", "C"]
>>> C = ["X1", "X2"]
>>> A, B, C = (list(x) for x in (izip(*izip_longest(A, B, C, fillvalue='X'))))
>>> A
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
>>> B
['A', 'B', 'C', 'X', 'X']
>>> C
['X1', 'X2', 'X', 'X', 'X']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `max()` to get the max length and then append list to `B` and `C`.

If you want to replace `X` with `P`, you can use a list comprehension `[i.replace('X','P') for i in C]` to get `['P1','P2']`:

```
>>> m=max(len(A),len(B),len(C))
>>> B+['X']*(m-len(B))
['A', 'B', 'C', 'X', 'X']
>>> [i.replace('X','P') for i in C]+['X']*(m-len(C))
['P1', 'P2', 'X', 'X', 'X']
```